# Python read an archive for a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I read a file and transform the information of the following line into a python dictionary:

file:

```
orig sorted(list(set(loadDB('db/path_orig'))))
dest sorted(list(set(loadDB('db/path_dest'))))
md_dest ''.join(loadDB('db/path_md_dest'))
main ''.join(loadDB('db/main_batch'))
copy ''.join(loadDB('db/copy_batch'))
```

expected outcome:

```
option = {
        'orig': sorted(list(set(loadDB('db/path_orig')))),
        'dest': sorted(list(set(loadDB('db/path_dest')))),
        'md_dest': ''.join(loadDB('db/path_md_dest')),
        'main': ''.join(loadDB('db/main_batch')),
        'copy': ''.join(loadDB('db/copy_batch'))
    }
```

I tried:

```
with open('text') as f:
    d = dict(x.rstrip().split(None, 1) for x in f)
```

outcome:

```
d = {
    'main': "''.join(loadDB('db/main_batch')),", 
    'copy': "''.join(loadDB('db/copy_batch'))", 
    'dest': "sorted(list(set(loadDB('db/path_dest')))),", 
    'md_dest': "''.join(loadDB('db/path_md_dest')),", 
    'orig': "sorted(list(set(loadDB('db/path_orig')))),"
}
```

Comment: Alright, that sounds like workable task, what have you tried?

Comment: My problem is, I want `"''.join(loadDB('db/main_batch'))"` not a string but a function `''.join(loadDB('db/main_batch'))`

Comment: Import `ast` module. Loop over items and run `ast.literal_eval()` on the values and store it back into those keys.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
import ast

with open('text','r') as f:
    d1 = {line.strip().split(' :: ')[0]:line.strip().split(' :: ')[1] for line in f}

d2={}
for k,v in d1.iteritems():
    d2[k] = ast.literal_eval(v)
```

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Comment: Is there no other method for me to convert a string into a function?

Comment: I'm on python2.7, but this will work perfectly on 3 as well. I can't test your functions. So can't really say what's wrong.

Comment: Yes it works perfectly `d2[k] = ast.literal_eval(v)` where I get the error: `ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Call object at 0x036347B0>`

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of an out-of-the-box solution that assumes you are running in a Unix-like environment.

First run the following on the command line:

```
echo 'option = {' > file.py
sed 's/ /: /' file >> file.py
echo '}' >> file.py
```

You have now created an importable Python script `file.py` from the original `file`. You can now do

```
import file
```

in your driver script.

If formatting is important, you may want to use the following `sed` command as an alternative:

```
sed -e 's/ /: /' -e 's/^/    /' file.txt
```